# Can't use JSON_EXTRACT when json name has dash inside

Tags: mysql, sql

When I use JSON type with fieldname containing dash i get **Invalid JSON path expression** error

How to repeat:

```
create table tt (j1 json);
insert into tt values ('{"cache-size":10}'); <-- insert went fine
select JSON_EXTRACT(j1,"$.cache-size") from tt;
```

ERROR 3143 (42000): Invalid JSON path expression. The error is around character position 12.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Names of keys must be double-quoted strings or valid ECMAScript identifiers

Hyphens are not allowed in ECMAScript identifiers, so the name needs to be **quoted** in the path expression.
This seems to work:

```
select JSON_EXTRACT(j1, '$."cache-size"') from tt;
```

```
id    | JSON_EXTRACT(j1, '$."cache-size"')
------+----------  
1     | 10
```